# INSPECTDB and INSPECTDB_REFACTOR generate empty models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, inspectdb

I  have django project and one app.
I haven't models, and I want to generate them from exist postgres database.
I tried `python manage.py inspectdb_refactor --database=default --app=igt` and `python manage.py inspectdb --database=default` but for the first event django generates paths with only `__inti__.py`, and for the second event (inspectdb) django generates empty models.py. What is wrong?
Connection is ok (so DATABASE configs is ok), apps was defined on setting.. what the problem?
My setting.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os, sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '--------------------------------------------------'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition


MYOWN_APPS = [
    'igt'
    ]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'polymorphic',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'dynamic_raw_id',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_gis',
    'django_filters',
    'inspectdb_refactor',

] + MYOWN_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lesoved.urls'



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lesoved.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'igt',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '00.xxxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        'PORT': '0000',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**UPD:** now inspectdb (after migration) has been generated some Django classes in models.py:

```
class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)
```

but classes from postgres database were not generate

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: @ not2acoder, no one error! models.py was generated, but file is empty. only from django.db import models, northing more. I ENGINE sett in DATABASE can be reason?

Comment: @not2acoder could you look on UPD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using of public scheme was a problew. I have been to change a public scheme on necessary scheme in a OPTIONS config of DATABASE (settings.py)

```
DATABASE{
    'default':{
        //some configs
       'OPTIONS': {
              'options': '-c search_path=myownschema'
        }
    }
}
```